# Is It Possible to Style React Components After Creation?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

So essentially I have a React component `<Bore />`. And I have an array of `Bores` and I need to style the first and last element of the array. I know how to access these elements with `Bores[0]` and `Bores[Bores.length-1]`. But my problem is figuring out how to style these specific components after creation. Would I have to do something like `className += "newClass"`. I'm only 2 days into using React so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could pass them a prop...

Comment: or use `:first-child` and `:last-child`

Comment: And of course it's the simple things I didn't think of. I appreciate your help! lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use style objects instead of mutating the class list. The important thing to remember is that CSS properties are camel case. Something like

```
class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            style: {
                backgroundColor: "green",
                marginRight: "10px"
            }
        } 
    }
    changeStyle = () => {
        this.setState(() => {
            return {
                style: {
                    marginLeft: "10px",
                    backgroundColor: "red"
                }
            }
        })
    }
    render = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child style={this.state.style} changeStyle={this.changeStyle}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const Child = ({ style, changeStyle }) => {
    return (
        <div style={style} onClick={changeStyle}>
          <h1>Dummy</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rfhmxts2/ see here, click on the div to change it's background color and margins